# how to restore terminal commands?

Tags: command-line, bash, homebrew

I spent most of the day trying to install Ruby on my MacOs (from 2014, version 10.11.6 -- I can't update to higher).  I finally got chruby installed with Homebrew and then tried to follow the insructions [here on github](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby/wiki/ruby) for installing ruby. The first instruction is to run

```
wget https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.2/ruby-3.2.0.tar.xz
```

But when I ran it, it said -bash: wget: command not found

Then I tried `ls` to see what would happen(as another random command from the terminal) and i got the same response:  `bash: ls: command not found`

Then I tried to open and run programs from the command line and got the same response. I turned the computer on and off and still no change.

Interestingly, I can run homebrew commands

`brew doctor` prints an output, and I can do `cd`

`vim` is unavailable as is `nano`

The only thing I touched in my .bash_profile was this line that I added

`# source /Users/mm/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh`

but it's the same whether I leave it commented or uncomment it out.

How can I restore the terminal commands (with related question, why did this happen)?

Comment: It happened because the PATH environment variable is unset or set incorrectly. What do you get from this: echo "$PATH"

Comment: _Interestingly, I can run homebrew commands_ : I don't find it that much interesting. `brew` is usually in /usr/local/bin, while `ls` is usually in `/bin`. So just fix your PATH, and off you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, open a new tab/window in Terminal and check whether the problem remains. If it does:

- Run `echo $PATH` to see what is wrong with it (in such cases, it's usually either empty or set to a strange value which might help in step 3 below).
- Run `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` in your current shell to temporarily restore the path.
- Then look into the startup files of your shell (`.profile`, `.bashrc` and anything called from there) to check where exactly PATH gets set wrong.